# Jquery Json not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following which works fine:

```
      $('<li><a id=' + loc.locId + ' href="/DataEntry"  rel="external">' + loc.locName + '</a></li>').appendTo("#btnList");

       $("#btnList a").click(function () {
            alert(siteName);
            localStorage["dataEId"] = $(this).attr("id");
            localStorage["dataESiteName"] = siteName;
            localStorage["dataESysName"] = sysName;
            localStorage["dataELocName"] = $(this).text();

         }
```

When I have the following, I can't even get to the click to display an alert message:

```
$.getJSON('/Home/GetLocType', { "locId": loc.locId }, function (result) {
    var str = JSON.stringify(result);

    if (str == '1') {
        $('<li><a id=' + loc.locId + ' href="/DataEntry"  rel="external">' + loc.locName + '</a></li>').appendTo("#btnList");
    } else {
        $('<li><a id=' + loc.locId + ' href="/DataEntry/PotableForm"  rel="external">' + loc.locName + '</a></li>').appendTo("#btnList");
    }
    $("#btnList").listview('refresh');
});

$("#btnList a").click(function () {
    alert(siteName);
    localStorage["dataEId"] = $(this).attr("id");
    localStorage["dataESiteName"] = siteName;
    localStorage["dataESysName"] = sysName;
    localStorage["dataELocName"] = $(this).text();
}
```

Note sure what the difference is. I need to use Json as based on value, I need to go to a either of the 2 hyperlinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use event delegation since anchor is created dynamically in your ajax call or bind the event (*only for the added element*) inside the ajax success callback. [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) syntax will work if your jquery version >= 1.7 for earlier versions take a look at [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
  $("#btnList").on('click', 'a', function () {
        alert(siteName);
        localStorage["dataEId"] = $(this).attr("id");
        localStorage["dataESiteName"] = siteName;
        localStorage["dataESysName"] = sysName;
        localStorage["dataELocName"] = $(this).text();

    }
```

Your first syntax works because it binds the click event to the anchor that exists underneath `btnList`, but it doesn't bind event to the ones added during the ajax calls in a later point in time.